# Quiz in locked mode without managed Chromebooks?

Tags: testing, test-design

Google Forms enables locked mode (where students cannot move to other tabs or apps without submitting the form) only if students use certain laptops called Chromebooks.

I'm looking for any platform to create Math tests (thus, possibly compatible with Equatio or any other friendly way of displaying formulas and plots) that enables a locked mode for other kind of laptops and mobile devices, too.

I tried with Microsoft Forms, but I wasn't able to set the locked mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand how you'd expect this to work technically: Is the operating system expected to give a browser application control over the handling of its processes? (It hopefully won't.)

Comment: I wonder if this question is on topic because it is not specific to math and completely about device management.